# Does Backbone trigger a 'change' event when load data from a local file?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to test the change event of backbone collection, using this code:

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Item,
  url: "data.json"
});
var collection = new ItemCollection();
collection.bind("change", function() {cosole.log("collection changed.");});
collection.fetch();
```

then I change the json file manually and call collection.fetch() again, no 'change' event happens, is it because I use a local json file or .fetch method cannot trigger 'change' event?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because fetching a collection calls the reset method, a `reset` event is fired.

> **fetch** *collection.fetch([options])*
> .... When the model data returns from the server, ***the collection will reset***...
>
> **reset** *collection.reset(models, [options])*
> ... Use reset to replace a collection with a new list of models (or attribute hashes), ***triggering a single "reset" event*** at the end....

If you specify the option `{ add: true }` in the fetch method, models are added to the collection instead of replacing it, so a `add` event is fired.

---

The `change` event is triggered when a model changes, so basically when the method `.set()` is called on a model.

Comment: thanks, so the change event is mainly for client modification of data, cannot be observed when update data from server, instead need to set reset handler when fetch data, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

'change' event gets trigger when one of the collection attribute changes.
Eventhough you changed the file on your own, I couldn't find any file attribute in the **ItemCollection** .The two attribute you are having is a model object and a string.So I guess that's why the 'change' event is not getting triggered